# Handle compressed logs in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have zip files which has log files.My scenario from the zip file need to extract it and then parse it with logstash?.Could anyone guide me this would be very helpful.Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: Its to add tags on what platform you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logstash itself doesn't have any input plugins to process log files inside zip archives, but as long as you extract the files yourself to a directory that you've configured Logstash to look for log files in you'll be fine. The standard [file input plugin](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/inputs/file) accepts wildcards, so you could say

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/some/path/*.log"]
  }
}
```

to have Logstash process all files in the /some/path directory (you'd probably want to assign a type to the messages too).

If the names of the files inside the zip archives aren't unique you'll have to make sure you don't overwrite existing files when you unzip the archives. Or, probably better, extract each archive into a directory of its own and have Logstash process the whole tree:

```
input {
  file {
    path => ["/some/path/*/*.log"]
  }
}
```

Logstash isn't capable of deleting processed logs or moving them out of the way, so that's something you'll have to take care of too.

Comment: Sure you could unzip the logs, but lets check a little example of my daily use. My application generates around 2gb of log a day, shouldnt there be a better way to feed that into logstash? I'm not confortable transfering 2gb of raw text from a single client through the network just to get log files.